# What's the minimum required Squid config to make a public proxy server?

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to configure Squid3 proxy server that any IP address on the internet can access, but default settings horrible and whatever I do it keeps giving `TCP_DENIED/403`

What's the minimum config that enables me:

- Any IP address can access
- All out ports are accessible
- SSL + CONNECT enabled

I'll then start implementing further features, however right now I keep getting this error in all configurations I've tried.

Comment: This sounds like a Really Bad Idea. And I'm having a lot of difficulty coming up with a scenario where we might do this in a **professional** environment.

Comment: Does ServerFault require that all questions relate to a professional environment?

Comment: @PaulGear http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic - so, yes.

Comment: Fair enough. That reduces the likelihood that this is on-topic. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelHampton "Professionals" can't run proxy businesses now?

Comment: @TheLQ Professional proxy businesses don't have wide open proxies. That just invites abuse and will likely result in immediate blacklisting by RBLs and such.

Comment: My two cents - I could see where you own a firewall and DMZ and POST the DMZ you don't want to care/bother with setting up yet-another seemingly pointless security check that has cost structure associated to maintaining. Specifically - you maybe on EC2 with security groups that block all but specific IPs, and then also have a VIP, but INSIDE your protected network, you want anybody to have access to a proxy. However, this is a very small edge case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although a Really Bad Idea™, just add `acl all src all` to the top of your ACL list.

Again, this is **not** a good idea whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

Like the other posters, i'm going to call this a bad idea until proven otherwise (although i can think of a couple of good reasons to do it).

Instead of the acl suggested by Nathan C i'd suggest:

- `http_access allow all` (instead of `http_access deny all`, which is the default)
- `acl Safe_ports port 1-65535` (instead of the `Safe_ports` entries in the default config)
- `acl SSL_ports port 1-65535` (instead of the `SSL_ports` entries in the default config)
- If you're trying to create an anonymised service, set `forwarded_for off` and `via off`.

Again, do you really want to do this?

Comment: well, he is dr evil..